# Display text on an ImageView with flexible bounds

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, android-constraintlayout

i'm using glide v4 to load an image from an url into an `ImageView`. Like this:

```
GlideApp.with(view.context)
        .load(url)
        .into(view)
```

The image is inside a `ViewPager2`. So my `ConstraintLayout` has to have `match_parent` as width and height. This is my layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The images can be of different sizes. Some are taller than wide and some wider than tall. With `match_parent` on the view it always fills as much space as possible. That's what i want. But the image bounds will always fill the whole screen. Now i need to add a text overlay to the bottom of this image without exceeding the actual image inside the `ImageView`. I tried adding the following `TextView` and using constraints:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_view"
            android:text="Some text overlay"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#000000" />
```

Because my `ImageView`'s bounds are `match_parent` the `TextView`'s black background stretches over the complete screen. Setting the `ImageView`'s width and height to `wrap_content` (even with `adjustViewBounds="true"`) always results in zero width and height because the image is loading while the first layout happens.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUupz.png)

How can i show a lazy loaded image taking as much space up as possible with correct view bounds (in portrait and landscape) so i could use layout constraints correctly on other views without knowing any aspect ratio, width or height beforehand?
**Alternative:** How to solve my specific problem with another layout/`ViewGroup`?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question

Comment: It is not recommended to use `match_parent` for direct children of ConstraintLayout. Try using `0dp` (to match constraints) for both dimensions in the ImageView and see if that helps you with the issue.

Comment: Using 0dp for both results in the exact same layout. The textView is still too wide

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help but I don't fully understand the question. Here's a tip. if you want the image to fill the entire parent, then set the constraints to meet the parent with no padding (Assuming you are using Constraintlayout which you should). And since you are not sure the aspect ratio of the images, you have to either use ScaleType attribute of fitXY or CenterCrop so that the image fills the entire parent. fitXY can distort the image so I usually go with centerCrop.

Comment: Hi, I need to show the complete image without distortion. So fitCenter would be what I need. The problem is the text overlay. See my linked image. The text block should not be wider than the actual image

Answer (score 0):

I edited this custom `ImageView` code a little bit (https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo/blob/master/src/com/example/staggeredgridviewdemo/views/ScaleImageView.java):

```
package de.xxx.xxx.controls

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView

/**
 *
 * This view will auto determine the width or height by determining if the
 * height or width is set and scale the other dimension depending on the images dimension
 *
 * This view also contains an ImageChangeListener which calls changed(boolean isEmpty) once a
 * change has been made to the ImageView
 *
 * @author Maurycy Wojtowicz
 */
class ScaleImageView : AppCompatImageView {
    var imageChangeListener: ImageChangeListener? = null
    private var scaleToWidth =
        false // this flag determines if should measure height manually dependent of width

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle
    ) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        this.scaleType = ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
    }

    override fun setImageBitmap(bm: Bitmap?) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm)
        if (imageChangeListener != null) imageChangeListener!!.changed(bm == null)
    }

    override fun setImageDrawable(d: Drawable?) {
        super.setImageDrawable(d)
        if (imageChangeListener != null) imageChangeListener!!.changed(d == null)
    }

    override fun setImageResource(id: Int) {
        super.setImageResource(id)
    }

    interface ImageChangeListener {
        // a callback for when a change has been made to this imageView
        fun changed(isEmpty: Boolean)
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec)
        val heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)
        var width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        var height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        /**
         * if both width and height are set scale width first. modify in future if necessary
         */
        scaleToWidth = if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            true
        } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            false
        } else throw IllegalStateException("width or height needs to be set to match_parent or a specific dimension")

        if (drawable == null || drawable.intrinsicWidth == 0) {
            // nothing to measure
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
            return
        } else {
            if (scaleToWidth) {
                val iw = this.drawable.intrinsicWidth
                val ih = this.drawable.intrinsicHeight
                var heightC = width * ih / iw
                if (height > 0) if (heightC > height) {
                    // dont let hegiht be greater then set max
                    heightC = height
                    width = heightC * iw / ih
                }
                this.scaleType = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
                setMeasuredDimension(width, heightC)
            } else {
                // need to scale to height instead
                var marg = 0
                if (parent != null) {
                    if (parent.parent != null) {
                        marg += (parent.parent as RelativeLayout).paddingTop
                        marg += (parent.parent as RelativeLayout).paddingBottom
                    }
                }
                val iw = this.drawable.intrinsicWidth
                val ih = this.drawable.intrinsicHeight
                width = height * iw / ih
                height -= marg
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now using this gives me my wanted result:

[See here (Image in landscape)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPeSs.png)